# Exposed filter value into the session and cookie?

Tags: views, caching

I want users visit my site regularly. And I need to store their settings to session (cookie). These settings are: Views Exposed Filter on the FrontPage (like to hide materials from the black list users).

So I have the FrontPage View and Taxonomy Term View. These views have exposed filter.

Once visitor selected values in this filter they should to store during he browsing the site and more when he visit site again.

I do not want to use JavaScript. I want to store cookie with php and to get it with php.

And I want drupal cache all pages for all possible filter values.

Please, have I to write a new Drupal CMS or where have I to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the "Configure filter criterion" form.

[image: Remember the settings]

Test this one. I guess it will write a cookie for the user.

Comment: I think this option work only for authenticated users. For Anonymous this will cache site with one user selected and all will see his choice.